# Using Groovy JSON builder

Tags: json, grails, groovy, grails-controller

I've seen several really cool examples of Groovy and Grails JSON builder. Here's one:
http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/03/22/grails-protip-dynamically-creating-json-in-grails-2-0-with-jsonbuilder/

Right now I'm using a controller to generate test list using using collect and then render the list into a JSON object. Does anyone know how to take the above example and put it into a controller?

Here's what my controller looks like:

```
class TreeMapController {

def list(){

    def results = myDomain.list()

    def test = [:] //Test List

    test=[] 

    def i = 0 //index key for parent

    //Generate list for fancyTree
    for (record in results){
        test.add([key:i++,folder:true, title: record.name, guid: record.id,
                children:record.subResults.collect{[title:it.name]}

        ])
    }

    //render response types
    withFormat {
        html test
        json {render test as JSON}
        xml {render test as XML}
    }
}

}
```

To call this using json request I provide the link: localhost/project/list.json
if I was to call the example provided (link to using JSON builder) above how would I call or make the request.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question in the last paragraph?

Comment: I was trying to say that with the above controller that I have created, to access the JSON file I use the link localhost/project/list.json.  However if I was to use JSON builder, how would I provide link to the json file.

Comment: You mean like `json {render builder.toString()}`?

Comment: yes, I'll try that. Sorry, I'm new to Grail's and I was thrown into it without training.

Comment: No worries :-) Hope we can help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should have a look on [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/Documentation) to understand basic concepts

Here, you have a controller that will respond to `${baseUrl}/treeMap/list` url, that is to say `http://localhost:8080/treeMap/list` as per the defaults

You'll have to request the URL with a `Content-type: text/json;` header, I think, to make it work